# Fast removing duplicate rows between multiple files

Tags: linux, performance, duplicates

I have 10k files with 80k rows each and need to compare, and - either delete the duplicate lines or replace them by "0". ultrafast since I have to do it +1000 times.

the following script is fast enough for files with less than 100 rows. now tcsh

```
import csv
foreach file ( `ls -1 *` )
split -l 1 ${file} ${file}.
end
find *.* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha512sum | awk '($1 in aa){print $2}(!($1 in  aa)){aa[$1]=$2}' | xargs -I {} cp rowzero {} 
cat ${file}.* > ${file}.filtered
```

where "rowzero" is just a file with a... zero. I have tried python but haven't found a fast way. I have tried pasting them and doing all nice fast things (awk, sed, above commands, etc.) but the i/o slows to incredible levels when the file has over more than e.g. 1000 columns. I need help, thanks a million hours!.

Comment: did you try to put `awk '!a[$0]++' $file >/tmp/f && mv /tmp/t $file` in your loop, was it too slow?

Comment: Oh, the duplicated lines are not duplicated in single file, but in all files?

Comment: yep the input files contain just a single row of numbers. I guess I could transpose it and then apply awk for each column in the 10Gb file as you suggested. I will see how fast this is...

Comment: OK almost getting there! so making an assoc. awk array for the transposed ("tr '\n' '\t'") file of 80k columns is also very slow... if only I could make something like "for(ii=1, ii++, ii<=NF){!ii[$ii]++}" work...(i.e. making ii[] arrays for each column)

Comment: ok! this is the fastest awk code one so far, after transposing.  Just need to think how to recover the original input format, thanks @Kent ! `{
    
    for(ii=1;ii<=NF;ii++){
 aa[ii,$ii]=$ii
    }
}
END{
    for (n in aa) {
 split(n, bb, SUBSEP)
 print aa[bb[1], bb[2]]
    }
   
}`

Comment: You want to keep only unique lines? Must the original files be edited, or can you create one (set of) result-files?

Answer (score 1):

ok this is so far the fastest code that I could make, which works on a transposed and "cat" input. As explained before, "cat"-ed input ">>" works fine however "paste" or "pr" code gives nightmares pasting another column in, say, +1GB files, and that is why we need to transpose.  e.g. 
each original file looks like

```
1 
2 
3 
4
```

...
if we transpose and cat the first file with others the input for the code will look like:

```
1 2 3 4 .. 
1 1 2 4 .. 
1 1 1 4 ..
```

The code will return the original "aka retransposed pasted" format with the minor detail of shuffled rows

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3
2 3 4
..
```

The repeated rows were effectively removed. below the code,

HOWEVER THE CODE IS NOT GENERAL! it only works with 1-digit integers since the awk array indexes are not sorted. Could someone help to generalize it? thanks!

`{for(ii=1;ii<=NF;ii++){aa[ii,$ii]=$ii}}END{mm=1; for (n in aa) {split(n, bb, SUBSEP);
if (bb[1]==mm){cc=bb[2]; printf ( "%2s", cc)}else{if (mm!=bb[1]){printf "\n%2s", bb[2] }; mm=bb[1]}}}`

Comment: SOLVED! Use gawk 4.0.2 with PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" to "sort" the input array scan, that way you can generalize this "minimal for" code for floats and whateva.